# Integrating DotNetNuke with an existing web site

Tags: asp.net, iis, integration, dotnetnuke

As part of a redesign for one of my clients I'd like to move them to DotNetNuke to gain the CMS and blogging features.  Their existing site has some custom ecommerce functionality that an off-the-shelf package just can't handle, so I'm inclined to leave it and just re-skin to match the new site.

The challenge is making this all fit together.

I could create two physical web sites in IIS, for example:

`www.website.com` <-- DNN install

and

`shop.website.com` <-- Existing ecommerce

This would keep things isolated, but I see a problem with the SSL certificate.  It's tied to `www.website.com`, so now I'd either need two -- one for `www.` and one for `shop.` -- or I need a wildcard certificate.  Either adds ongoing expenses for the client.

Can you think of any other, more elegant approaches?

- I could try to encapsulate the existing site into a DNN module, but that seems like a lot of work.
- I could also try doing something tricky with iframes, but again I think this would just further complicate things.

Hopefully one of you can think of something I haven't.  Thanks!

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598235/deploying-dotnetnuke-and-separate-asp-net-application-together-possible-issues/

Comment: This seems related too, but I'm not sure I follow the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926958/adding-independent-aspx-asmx-pages-into-dotnetnuke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having both sites separate is one way to go. I would personal prefer having the ecommerce portion as a virtual directory or application of the main website. This way you can easily share DNN's resources in the shop. Such as the forms authentication information, user controls or any other stuff you would like to slowly integrate into your shop, you can. And you could still use ONE ssl certificate, if you want. Perhaps you want to create a user control to display the logged in user that is in your main DNN site:

```
lblUserName.Text = UserInfo.Username
```

So instead of two IIS websites:

```
website.com (DNN Install)
shop.website.com (custom ecommerce)
```

I would recommend putting shop under the DNN install so you can have https://website.com/shop <-- one ssl will cover it all. You can also have a seperate website https://shop.website.com if you'd like that points to https://website.com/shop (alias like)

```
website.com (DNN Install)
|
|--- Shop (custom ecommerce)
|--- Other DNN folders
```

Comment: I agree, this is how I've done it in the past. If the E-Commerce app is an ASP.NET application, you'll probably need to make changes to both web.config files to prevent unwanted inheritance of various settings.

Comment: I like the approach in general.  It's slightly complicated by the fact that the DNN install is used by more than one portal.  I wouldn't want a physical directory in the DNN structure that could be accessed by other web sites.  Could a virtual directory be used for that one specific web site?

Comment: Sure, you could use a virtual directory / application that resides elsewhere and not in the physical location of the DNN installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the SSL cert I had to do something similar to incorporate a blog with an eCommerce site. In my case I used BlogEngine on the sub-domain and reskinned it to match the 'parent' site. I think your approach is correct and yes, you will probably need to obtain a wildcard certificate; if the price of this is a problem for your client then that in itself should raise a red flag?

More info on SSLs:

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/01/28/top-7-myths-about-https/

Comment: Price may not be a concern for the client, but I just want to be sure I cover all the options.  Price -- no matter how great or small -- is a factor.  In the end, a second certificate for $20 / yr might be the easiest option.  It's cheaper to have two than one wildcard as it turns out.